# How to INSERT INTO a range of numbers into a MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

How would I insert a range of numbers into a MYSQL table? I'm missing something very obvious!

Here's my example:

**MYSQL**

```
INSERT INTO stock_figures (product_id)
VALUES (13275 BETWEEN 13341)
```

I want to insert into the `product_id` column all of the numbers between 13275 and 13341 inclusive.

Can somebody please assist? 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I would like to avoid creating a procedure or a temporary table as this is only being used for a single query. I feel this qualifies as different enough to not be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @RaviParekh - just as a single query please. Thanks

Comment: The duplicate pointed to **has answers that 'avoid creating a procedure or a temporary table'**. So after your 'update', it's still a dupe.